# Rails: updating a nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have two models, Proposals and Proposal Replies. In my routes, I've nested Proposal Replies within Proposals. I have this form:

```
<%= form_for proposal_proposal_reply_path(@proposal, @proposal_reply), :remote => true do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_area :body %>
  <%= f.submit 'Submit' %>
<% end %>
```

When I click submit, I get a routing error:

```
No route matches [POST] "/proposals/1/proposal_replies/4/edit"
```

Why is it trying to POST to edit, instead of just PUTing? I can hack it into working by inserting some url options like so:

```
<%= form_for proposal_proposal_reply_path(@proposal, @proposal_reply), :remote => true, :method => :put, :url => {:action => :update} do |f| %>
```

This doesn't feel like the Rails way, though. What else could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you don't need to use a path helper at all. If you have the correct route definitions:

```
resources :proposals do
  resources :proposal_replies
end
```

you should be able to pass `[@proposal, @proposal_reply]` to `form_for`:

```
<%= form_for [@proposal, @proposal_reply], :remote => true do |f| %>
```

Comment: That does the trick! I'm surprised the path helper would interfere here. What's curious is that according to the [Rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html), update uses the same path helper as show and delete.